# I used Laravel to response to JSON. The data that is answered is passed to the String value. How to solve it

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

I used Laravel to response to JSON. The data that is answered is passed to the String value. How to solve it[image]

my laravel code is
[image]

If you have the same experience as me, please help me.

my front code is

```
 getUser() {
      let token = localStorage.usertoken;
      let config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        }
      };
      return axios
        .get("/api/auth/profile", config)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(typeof res.data);

          var obj = JSON.parse(res.data);
          console.log(obj);
          return res.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

back code is

```
 public function getAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        try {
            if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
            }
        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {
            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {
            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
        }
        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }
```

response is

```
"{"id":80,"email":"123@123.com","name":"123123","ro…updated_at":"2020-05-05T05:34:01.000000Z"}Laravel"
```

I don't even know if there's Laravel at the end of JSON and Why a string

Comment: You want to pass data as String??

Comment: Try with `return response()->json($user);`.

Comment: @AA Noman No, I'd like to receive it in json object.  I checked the type of the value that is response and it was String.

Comment: @Tpojka I already tried it, but the result was the same.

Comment: You can use [json parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on frontend.

Comment: @Tpojka Unexpected token L in JSON at position 206 This error appears.

Comment: Instead of images, post your frontend code (block we are trying to solve issue here).

Comment: @ Tpojka  added a code